# On clicking Sidebar toggle button takes back to default page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sidebar, togglebutton

I have a simple toggle using hooks to show/hide sidebar. The toggle button works fine as far as showing and hiding sidebar is concerned. When I click on the toggle button it opens the sidebar. And when I click on any of the link from the side bar, the link takes me to the destined page. But now when I click on the toggle button to open the sidebar, instead of staying on the same page it navigates to the default page.

This is the User page

```
function User() {

 const [isOpen, setIsopen] = useState(false);

  const ToggleSidebar = () => {
    !isOpen ? setIsopen(true) : setIsopen(false);
  }



  return (
    <div className='userheader'>
      <div className='usercontainer'>
        <div className='signout-btn-position' >
          <SignOut />
        </div>
        <div className={`sidebar ${isOpen ? 'active' : ''}`}>
          <div className="sd-header">
            <h4 className="mb-0">Sidebar Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="sd-body">
            <ul>
              <li>{userName ? <div id='username'><FaUserCircle style={{ marginBottom: '4px', marginRight: '4px' }} />{userName}</div> : "Guest User"}</li>
              <i><a href='/user/anesthesiatheory' className='link-btn' >Anesthesia</a></i>
              <i><a href='/user/anesthesiatheory' className='link-btn' >Integaumentary</a></i>
              <i><a href='/user/anesthesiatheory' className='link-btn' >Musculoskeletal</a></i>
              <i><a href='/user/anesthesiatheory' className='link-btn' >Cardio & Respiratory</a></i>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Link className="btn" onClick={ToggleSidebar}><FaBars /></Link>
        <div className={`sidebar-overlay ${isOpen ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={ToggleSidebar}></div>
      </div>
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default User
```

and this is my App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(

  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} >
      <Route index element={<About />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="guestuser" element={<GuestUser />} />
      <Route path="User" element={<User />}>
        <Route index element={<UserDefault />} />
        <Route path="anesthesiatheory" element={<AnesthesiaTheory />} />
        <Route path="anesquizmain01" element={<AnesMain01 />} />
        <Route path="anesquiz01" element={<AnesQuiz01 />} />
        <Route path="anesquizresult01" element={<AnesResult01 />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

What I want is that when I click on the toggle button, I want the sidebar to show without navigating me to default page. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Looking forwards for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You are using React-Router to make your app an SPA. Don't use an anchor tag with href in an react SPA, use useNavigate Hook to navigate by clicking on your <a> (but make the <a> a div, btn, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are using

```
<Link className="btn" onClick={ToggleSidebar}><FaBars /></Link>
```

which is redirecting to default page,
use `button` instead of `<Link>` to solve this;

```
<button className="btn" onClick={ToggleSidebar}><FaBars /></button>
```

also clean your function for  ToggleSidebar

from

```
  const ToggleSidebar = () => {
    !isOpen ? setIsopen(true) : setIsopen(false);
  }
```

to

```
const ToggleSidebar = () => {
    setIsopen(!isOpen)
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! it worked like charm. Also learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your toggle button from a `<Link>` element to maybe a `<button>` element. The `<Link>` element from react-router-dom acts as an anchor `<a>` (if you inspect it on your document, it displays as an anchor), and without the `href=""` property set, it will just redirect you to `/` or refresh the page. So change that line in the Users page as so:

```
<button className="btn" onClick={ToggleSidebar}><FaBars /></button>
```

**PS**
if you insist on keeping the `<Link>` tag, then maybe try preventing the default action in your `ToggleSidebar` function:

```
  const ToggleSidebar = (event) => {
    event.preventDefaul()
    !isOpen ? setIsopen(true) : setIsopen(false);
  }
```

then in the `<Link>` element:

```
<Link className="btn" onClick={ (event) => ToggleSidebar(event) }><FaBars /></Link>
```

Note that I haven't tried this on a `<Link>` or `<a>` tag in the past, and I am not sure if this will work, but the  fix ought to do it.

Hope this was helpful, let me know if you need any more help :)

Comment: there's no reason for using event handlers inside <Link> which is not navigating you anywhere (i.e. Links without to="" ),